# Why I am seeing "Terminated" error on eclipse while running this code

Tags: java, error-handling

```
public class Reverse {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char array[] = { 'a', 'x', 'y', 'd', 'd' };
        int length = array.length;
        for (int i = length - 1; i <= 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(array[i] + " ");
        }

    }
}
```

//Above is the code i am runnig and see the message as "Reverse[Java Application]"

Comment: `i <= 0` should be `i >= 0`

Answer (score 3):

`<terminated>` is just the status of the program.

Here, your code terminates because we never enter your loop since `i` is never `<= 0`

---

### Correction

```
char array[] = { 'a', 'x', 'y', 'd', 'd' };
int length = array.length;
for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(array[i] + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't getting anything (`<Terminated>`) because it is never running. Replace `<=` with `>=`.

Answer (score 1):

the login in the for is blocking the code to loop

change this:

```
for (int i = length - 1; i <= 0; i--) {
```

for this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        char array[] = { 'a', 'x', 'y', 'd', 'd' };
        int length = array.length;
        for (int i = 0; i <length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(" now in reverse order:" );
        //reverse order:
        for (int i = length-1; i >=0; i--) {
            System.out.println(array[i] + " ");
        }


}
```